# Why doesn't the DNS resolve after a nameserver change, despite a recursive DNS lookup being successful?

Tags: domain-name-system

I recently migrated a domain I own from Cloudflare to Netlify DNS, so I had to update my nameservers. When I run a recursive DNS lookup that bypasses DNS cache everything seems to be set up correctly:

```
$ dig howtogit.net +trace
(output truncated)
howtogit.net.       20  IN  A   159.65.199.87
;; Received 57 bytes from 198.51.44.1#53(dns1.p01.nsone.net) in 18 ms
```

However, a regular DNS lookup fails:

```
$ nslookup howtogit.net                                                                               
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find howtogit.net: SERVFAIL
```

I assume that if caching was at fault, Cloudflare would still resolve the lookup which it doesn't. A lookup at 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) also fails:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 howtogit.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 howtogit.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 63809
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;howtogit.net.          IN  A

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 23 13:05:50 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

Since DNS records are cached, I also tried [flushing Google's DNS cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache) for my NS and A records. I'm still getting the same result, despite the change having happened over 10 hours ago.

Is my configuration incorrect? How do I make sure my DNS can resolve properly again?

Comment: In cases like this, a tool like `dnsviz.net` should easily show you there is a DNSSEC problem. In fact you can clearly see the problem here: http://dnsviz.net/d/howtogit.net/W6d5WA/dnssec/  that you can compare to current working one: http://dnsviz.net/d/howtogit.net/W6kJlg/dnssec/

Comment: Yep, I figured it out. Ultimately I decided to migrate back to Cloudflare because Netlify DNS doesn't support DNSSEC. But good to know!

Comment: DNSSEC is hard, indeed. A compromise between the features it provides and the steps needed ot have it. In related cases, a troubleshooting tip: if a `dig` fails with SERVFAIL but if you redo the exact same one adding `+cd` and it does not fail anymore, then it probably means the problem is DNSSEC related. `+cd` disable DNSSEC checks, hence the possible difference. But SERVFAIL can happen for a lot of problems, there are no (for now) extended error codes in the DNS...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It would appear that the `howtogit.net` zone used to he signed, and that after switching nameservers it is no longer signed.

However, you have left the old `DS` record in place, indicating that the zone must be signed with some specific key.

Either remove the `DS` record or sign the zone again and update the `DS` record as necessary (the `DS` record is managed through your registrar).

If you look at the tail end of relevant `dig +trace` output it's actually quite clear that this must be the case (`DS` as part of referral but no `DNSKEY` on the authoritative end, or just no signatures if you query some other type):

```
$ dig +trace +all howtogit.net DNSKEY

...

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63298
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;howtogit.net.                  IN      DNSKEY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
howtogit.net.           172800  IN      NS      dns1.p01.nsone.net.
howtogit.net.           172800  IN      NS      dns2.p01.nsone.net.
howtogit.net.           172800  IN      NS      dns3.p01.nsone.net.
howtogit.net.           172800  IN      NS      dns4.p01.nsone.net.
howtogit.net.           86400   IN      DS      2371 13 2 F7822E035739507BFB9ED504B65FFE7A95698E58C069EF1DE754EED0 55E6799F
howtogit.net.           86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20180927051931 20180920040931 7934 net. POLNdGPgCCeF6ClG4ro1mkUI5DpqUuuLLeR4WCly1L5GbOTgPnzg02Nx 2Sse2dYDLJLB1EQYotZkvVm8GNFS5iE8UQlmp4GA3yxTgUeifw5PX6Eh kiJSip37/CyGCTy6OMPoVeMgQjLnrxt1aAOsnO5BszeGY7gD6ee/XHMO zc4=

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns1.p01.nsone.net.     172800  IN      A       198.51.44.1
dns2.p01.nsone.net.     172800  IN      A       198.51.45.1
dns3.p01.nsone.net.     172800  IN      A       198.51.44.65
dns4.p01.nsone.net.     172800  IN      A       198.51.45.65

;; Query time: 159 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:503:231d::2:30#53(2001:503:231d::2:30)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 23 11:35:52 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 402

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53062
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;howtogit.net.                  IN      DNSKEY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
howtogit.net.           3600    IN      SOA     dns1.p01.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1537613509 43200 7200 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 198.51.45.65#53(198.51.45.65)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 23 11:35:52 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103

$
```

Comment: You're spot on... looks like I forgot to disable DNSSEC before migrating. I removed the DS record with my registrar and 8.8.8.8 started resolving the domain correctly immediately.

Comment: @Pieter No problem. Thanks for not obfuscating the specifics, which otherwise tends to make these types of questions unnecessarily difficult to answer.